# A way to capture error output from ffmpeg/avconv in a bash script

Tags: bash, video, ffmpeg, libav

I am trying to batch convert a bunch of files and i am doing an simple listing of the converted files to a text document so that i can stop the script and continue from approximately were i started.

```
#! /bin/sh
source_dir="/home/eldamar/video"

find $source_dir -type f -regex ".*/.*\.\(mov\|mpg\|mkv\|avi\|m2v\|wmv\|flv\|m2ts\|vob\)" | {
while read file
  do
  ext=${file##*.}
  filename=${file##*/}
  basename=${filename%.*}
  dirname=${file%/*}
  touch converted.txt

  if grep -Fxq "$filename" converted.txt
  then
    echo "$(tput setaf 2)File "$filename" is allready converted, ignoring it :D$(tput setaf 7)"
  else
    # Extract subtitles for mkv files
    echo $ext
    if [ "$ext"=="mkv" ]; then
      # input.srt <- default subtitle
      # input.lang.srt <- other languages
      $sublang=""
      mkvinfo=$(mkvinfo $file | grep subtitles -B3 -A3)

      # Replace existing .srt
      # rm $dirname/$basename.srt

      # Extract subtitle from mkv
      # mkvextract tracks input.mkv -c ISO8859-1 3:$dirname/$basename.$sublang.srt
    fi

    avconv -y -i $file -map 0 -map -0:s -vcodec libx264 -acodec libfaac $dirname/$basename.mp4

    # Store the filename in list
    echo $filename >> converted.txt
  fi
  done;
}
```

There you go, subtitle extraction is also in progress but i am having trouble with knowing if avconv fails or not, is there a way?

**Edit** Somewhat done with this script now, here it is http://pastebin.com/trMDRaq5 thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most commands return a non-zero return value if an error occurred. You can either capture that return code or act on it with via `||` and `&&`.

Examples:

`avconv -y -i file1 ;  echo command finished`

`avconv -y -i file1 && echo command finished successfully.`

`avconv -y -i file1 || echo command finished but indicated failure!`

[Edit]

You can also check `$?` in the shell.
example:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/true
echo $?
/usr/bin/false
echo $?
```

True always succeeds. If you run the test script it will return a 0.
False always fails. If you run the test script it will return a non-0.  (in my case a 1, but that can vary).

Comment: [Hey that worked!](http://pastebin.com/MCAwBkd2)